# Jenkins pulling from Bonobo Git Server

Tags: windows, git, .net, jenkins

I have installed

- Jenkins
- Git plugin for SCM on Jenkins
- Bonobo Git Server

To configure Jenkins to build from Git I type in url, which is on my local network `http://devserv/Bonobo.Git.Server/<reponame>.git`, then i precede to type in username and password and i get this error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Could not init C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson8497551621296692258tmp
```

I have tried going to the folder and giving everyone full access rights to it, just for a test, but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you set up correct path to git executable in your Jenkins installation?

If not, go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System -> Git.

Comment: Perfect! You sir are my hero today :) Have my upvote :)